# pLSA - Probabilistic Latent Semantic Analysis, how to choose topic number?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, latent-semantic-analysis

I am learning about [pLSA (Probabilistic Latent Semantic Analysis)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_latent_semantic_analysis) right now, in the hopes of being able to apply it to biomolecular annotation prediction.

I have a very simple question: **How do you choose the number of topics / classes to use in the algorithm?** I've searched also literature but I did not find anything enough useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of topics / latent classes can be considered as a "meta" parameter of the model which has to be tuned using resampling (e.g. cross-validation) such that it minimizes your loss/risk function while keeping the run time of the algorithm reasonable.